# Angular 6 open pdf from byte array sent from WebAPI

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, pdf, httpclient

Hi I have issues opening pdf from byte array sent by WebAPI.

My Service:

```
getPdfDocument(): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient
            .get(this.configuration.serverUrl + this.configuration.getPdfDoc, {
                responseType: "arraybuffer" //tried with 'blob'
            });
}
```

My component:

> ```
> this.service.getPdfDocument()
>         .subscribe(data => {
>             var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });   
>             this.pdfContent = URL.createObjectURL(file);
>             window.open(this.pdfContent);
>         })
> ```

When I run it I get failed to load PDF document... I enabled pop ups still no joy...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

service:

```
getPdfDocument(): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' });
    return this.httpClient
               .get(this.configuration.serverUrl + this.configuration.getPdfDoc,
                    { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' as 'json', observe: 'response' as 'body' }
                });
        }
```

request:

```
this.service.getPdfDocument()
        .subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    this.openFileForPrint(data);
                });

openFileForPrint(data: HttpResponse<any>) {
        let fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        window.open(fileUrl, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
    }
```

### Server side

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getpdf(DateTime datum, int idlokacija)
{
    var r = _printService.getdata(datum, idlokacija);
    if (r == null)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    return SendPdfFile(r);
}

public static HttpResponseMessage SendPdfFile(string filePath, bool brisanje = true)
{
    var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    HttpResponseMessage response = new FileHttpResponseMessage(filePath, brisanje)
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
        Content = new StreamContent(stream)
    };
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    return response;
}
```

Comment: This implementation throws the following:
Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Comment: @tom33pr when you look to your server response how does your response header look like?

Comment: Joe see below:
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 230962
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 19 Oct 2018 11:05:35 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcZGFlcmEtcHJ6ZXpkemllY2tpdFxTb3VyY2VcUmVwb3NcUmV2aWV3IG9mIERlY2lzaW9uczJcUm9EXFJvRFdTXGFwaVxHZXRUcmltRG9jdW1lbnQ=?=

Comment: My WebApi controller returns byte array:
   [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/GetDocument")]
        public byte[] Get()

Comment: @tom33pr if you can edit api side of code in my edited answer you will find how my api side looks like.

Comment: Joe, thanks... I see you are using an MVC controller... most likely both the controller and the angular client are part of the same app. 
In my case I have .net (framework) WebAPI (controller) and .NET Core Web APP with Angular 6; both separate applications, running on separate appPools on IIS.

Comment: Many thanks Joe. Managed to get it to work with some further tweaking!