# how to access pdf dynamic from server

Tags: angular, reactjs

onclick on orderid i want to open that orderid invoice pdf.
as shown in code on click i am sending orderid to api and from there i am calling  invoice.getPDFFile(checkorderid).
and in readfile i am pssing path in settings.invoicesHome and file name in invoiceName and i am getting buffer.
[image]

```
.html
<a (click)="openpdf(element.orderId)">{{element.orderId}}</a>

.ts 
openpdf(orderId){
this.httpClient.get(`/adminApi/getPDFFile?orderId=${orderId}`)
  .subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
  window.open(res);
  });
}

.js
__api.getPDFFile = function(req , res) {
   var checkorderid = req.query.orderId;
   console.log(checkorderid);
   invoice.getPDFFile(checkorderid)
 .then(function () {
 res.send(data);
   })
   .catch(function (err) {
      console.log();
   });
}

.js
exports.getPDFFile = function(orderId){
   let invoiceName = 'invoice_' + orderId + '.pdf';
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      fs.readFile(path.join(settings.invoicesHome, invoiceName),(err, data)=>{
          if (err) {
              reject(err); 
          }
          else{
            resolve(data); 
          }
      });
  })
  .then((data)=>{
      console.log(data); 
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
      throw err; 
  })
```

i want to open pdf file onclick but i am getting buffer how to get pdf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anguar 6 open pdf from byte array sent from WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52888945/anguar-6-open-pdf-from-byte-array-sent-from-webapi)

Comment: can you help me with this code? what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
openpdf(orderId){
this.httpClient.get(`/adminApi/getPDFFile?orderId=${orderId}`)
  .subscribe(res => {
     let file = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });            
     var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
     window.open(fileURL);
  });
}
```

Comment: how to send res from api getPDFFile

Comment: __api.getPDFFile = function(req , res) {   
   var checkorderid = req.query.orderId;
   let invoiceName = 'invoice_' + checkorderid + '.pdf';
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            fs.readFile(path.join(settings.invoicesHome, invoiceName),(err, data)=>{if (err) {
                    reject(err); 
                }else{
                  resolve(data); 
                }
            });
        })
        .then((data)=>{
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            throw err; 
        })

Comment: i am getting data in byte how to get it in pdf format

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the file or blob, for example, if the server returns a Base 64:

```
static downloadFileBase64(base64File: string, extention: string, fileName: string) {
    const blob = this.generateBlobFromBase64File(base64File, extention, fileName);
    this.downloadFileFromBlob(blob, fileName);
}
private static downloadFileFromBlob(blob: Blob, fileName: string) {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    saveAs(blob, fileName);
}
```

Documentation:

> The URL.createObjectURL() static method creates a DOMString containing
>   a URL representing the object given in the parameter. The URL lifetime
>   is tied to the document in the window on which it was created. The new
>   object URL represents the specified File object or Blob object.

*SaveAs: import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';